# Cannot get relationships working with ember data

Tags: ember-data

I am using ember-data with RESTAdapter.

I have a module for **Tours**:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    title:  DS.attr('string'),
    trips: DS.hasMany('trip')
});
```

this is populated with REST json:

```
[{
   id: 132,
   title: 'Tour title',
},...]
```

and a module for **Trips**:

```
DS.Model.extend({
    tour: DS.belongsTo('tour'),
    startDate:  DS.attr('date')
});
```

this is populated with REST json:

```
{
   id: 12345,
   tour_id: 132,
   startDate: '2013-01-01',
}
```

I would like so that that when using trip model I could call `trip.tour.title` to get a title of the tour. And respectively I could make `tour.trips` to get a list of all trips for the tour.

But somehow this is not working any relationships usage don't even trigger an ajax request. So I wonder why? All the properties are mapped correctly, but not relationships.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was an old version of this libs, this is not relevant anymore.